# Can you go after ArcGIS Desktop Associate certification and immediately take ArcGIS Desktop Professional certification

Tags: arcgis-desktop, certification

I'm looking to build my GISP Portfolio and I need some points on the degree/cert section. Instead of just going after the ESRI ArcGIS Desktop Professional, will ESRI let me take the Associate Certification and then go after the professional immediately after? Or is there a wait time until you can take the Professional Cert?

The reason for this question is, If i can get both certification that would be more points I can add to my GISP Portfolio.

Comment: The MQC (Minimally Qualified Candidate) is very different for the two exams.  Since Professional is a superset of skills required for Associate, I would hope that GISP couldn't be gamed by this approach, but I don't think there's anything to stop you on the Esri side.

Comment: That is my concern. To be on the safe side, I will probably just go the professional cert. Do you know of any type of GIS Cert I can take?

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, you can take any exam at any time. The only "blocker" is the ability to schedule an exam through an accredited testing facility. If you can find a place that will allow you to book 1 exam on Monday and another exam on Tuesday, there is nothing to stop that.

This is based on my own experience taking multiple exams. I haven't taken any back to back, but the system of registering for an exam has never inferred in anyway that you'd be limited from taking exams.

My personal thought: Read which each exam will go into and try the practice questions. If you think you'll do well with the higher level exam, take that instead of doing the lower and then later doing the higher.